# inquire "from" or "to"?

Tags: word-choice

I have written: "They knew me from having seen me through the window, and from inquiring about me from John and Angel."
Should that be "to John", or even "of John," ?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest:

"They knew me from having seen me through the window, and from inquiring to John and Angel about me."